# Can't exit asynchronous process

Tags: ftp, python-asyncio

I have a problem with the exiting from the asynchronous process which is handled by asyncio. This is the ftp server + client project and I want to kill the client process after '**exit**' command.

The most important part of this code is here:

```
class FtpCommandsReceiver:
    def __init__(self, loop, sock):
        self.loop = loop
        self.sock = sock
        self.loop.create_task(self.recieve_data())
        self.commands_to_handle = {
                                        'exit': self.exit_handler
                                  }

    async def recieve_data(self):
        while True:
            self.data_to_send = input('ftp> ')
            if self.data_to_send == '':
                continue
            await self.loop.sock_sendall(self.sock, self.data_to_send.encode())
            try:
                await self.commands_to_handle.get(self.data_to_send)()
            except TypeError:
                pass
            self.received_data = await self.loop.sock_recv(self.sock, 10000)
            print(self.received_data.decode())
            if not self.received_data:
                break
        print('Connection closed by the server')
        self.sock.close()

    async def exit_handler(self):
        self.loop.stop()
        self.loop.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    FTP_connection = FtpConnection(loop)
    task = loop.create_task(FTP_connection.connect())
    try:
        loop.run_forever()
    finally:
        loop.close()
```

When it calls **exit_handler** method, the exception raises:

> Task exception was never retrieved
>       future:  exception=RuntimeError('Cannot close a running event loop',)>
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 239, in _step
>           result = coro.send(None)
>         File "FTPclient.py", line 54, in recieve_data
>           await self.commands_to_handle.get(self.data_to_send)()
>         File "FTPclient.py", line 66, in exit_handler
>           self.loop.close()
>         File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/unix_events.py", line 56, in close
>           super().close()
>         File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 94, in close
>           raise RuntimeError("Cannot close a running event loop")
>       RuntimeError: Cannot close a running event loop

I will be grateful for your help and thank you in advance!

Comment: Why do you close the event loop in `exit_handler`? Just call `stop` and leave it to the code at top-level to close the loop.

Comment: After your advise my program of the ftp client exits correctly, but I can't receive any data from the server by the socket in the new process.

Comment: Please consider reducing the code to a minimal runnable example that demonstrates the problem. It is hard to say what could be going on based solely on a description.